# Graph API multiquery fails with error: request failed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a multiquery to get some data about my friends and the pages they like.

```
{ 
  "query1": "SELECT uid, name, pic_square,birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY birthday_date",
  "query2": "SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)",
  "query3": "SELECT page_id,name,type,categories FROM page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query2)"
}
```

I had tested this multiquery about a month ago and it worked perfectly well, in fact i even have the data i collected from this multiquery but when i tried this again yesterday i got an error

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

I have proper permissions for this to execute.

**Strangely** when i limit my query it returns successfully.

```
{ 
  "query1": "SELECT uid, name, pic_square,birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY birthday_date",
  "query2": "SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1) LIMIT 20",
  "query3": "SELECT page_id,name,type,categories FROM page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query2)"
}
```

Is there some kind of limit on it now? How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Its a pagination issue. Apparently, one a use has a lot of contacts (2k+) the api will break unless if u fetch - say - 1K at a time.